# Bash returning a no such file when file exists

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run a grep command on a log file to grab a url to use for some functions. The problem is it keeps giving me a `No such file or directory` error whenever I try to run it. I thought this was bizarre so I prefixed it with an `ls` command to see if it did exist and lo and behold it is indeed there. Can someone tell me what the issue is, I have a feeling it's a syntax issue I'm not aware of but I can't figure it out.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 3` ;
do
        ssh user@member${i}.domain.com << EOF
        cd /home/path/member${i}/logs
        ls #I've printed the output of this below
        test=$( grep -oP "http:.*microwebapp/$" "messages.log" )
        echo "Test variable = ${test}"
        exit
EOF
done
```

The output of the `ls` command is the below:

```
console.log
messages.log
status.log
trace.log
```

So I'm really confused about what's going on, I've also tried replacing `"messages.log"` with `"./messages.log"` to no avail.

EDIT: here's the full output for one iteration of the loop:

```
grep: ./messages.log: No such file or directory
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
console.log
messages.log
status.log
trace.log
Test variable =
```

I suppose it's a little odd that the `grep` command throws an error before the `ls` command runs but I don't have an explanation for that either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of your "plain" heredoc, these lines execute on your **local** machine, **before** the shell hands control to ssh

```
    test=$( grep -oP "http:.*microwebapp/$" "messages.log" )
    echo "Test variable = ${test}"
```

Try:

```
ssh user@member${i}.domain.com << EOF
    cd /home/path/member${i}/logs
    ls #I've printed the output of this below
    test=\$( grep -oP "http:.*microwebapp/$" "messages.log" )
    #....^
    echo "Test variable = \$test"
    #.....................^
    exit
EOF
```

---

By "plain" heredoc, I mean the terminating word is unquoted. One can put single quotes around the word, and that effectively single quotes the whole heredoc:

```
ssh remote_host <<'END'
#.................^...^
h=$(hostname)
d=$(date)
echo The time at $h is $d
END
```

You can't do that in your code because you rely on expanding the local var `$i` to change to the correct directory.

Comment: What does the backslash signify, also, would you mind elaborating on what you mean by "plain" heredoc? Your fix is correct btw

Comment: it's the good old escaping, so it becomes a plain `$` (and not command execution).

Comment: well, it tells it to pass it as a regular character = no interpretation. the other side will do the interpretation.. but the caller doesn't know anything about this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath and glenn jackman thank you for the clarifications!